# Remove data within html tags - Python

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to remove some data between Html tags like for example,

I have:

```
<html> 
   <nav id="123"> .. balaba .. </nav> 
   <nav id="abeij"> .. baz..</nav> 
</html>
```

and I would like to remove all nav to get something like that `<html> </html>`.

I tried with BeautifulSoup and regex but I can not find informations
if I want to delete all nav, whatever their parameters and keep what's left

Comment: Could you post the sample of the code that you have tried so far that isn't working so we can help you debug it?

Comment: Best would be both tries, BeautifulSoup and regex. So we can assist with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Khalil's solution --  use regex to replace everything from the first `<nav` to the last `nav>` with nothing -- is probably the simplest answer for the specific example you gave.

For the more general issue of cleanly removing some set of html tags and their contents, you can use the `decompose()` method in BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = """<html> 
   <nav id="123"> .. balaba .. </nav> 
   keep me here
   <nav id="abeij"> .. baz..</nav> 
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
for i in soup('nav'):
    i.decompose()
soup

# <html>
# <body> 
#   keep me here
#
# </body></html>
```

You can use this to remove any set of tags that you can select with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re

>>> s = '<html> <nav id="123"> .. balaba .. </nav> <nav id="abeij"> .. baz..</nav> </html>'

>>> re.sub('<nav.*nav>','',s)
'<html>  </html>'
```

Comment: Is anyone supposed to understand this? Can you please explain your approach and what the code is doing?